# How to unzip a file from S3 and work with it in memory in AWS Lambda/NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip

I'm new to NodeJS and, as title says, I'm trying to read a zip file from S3 and work with its contents in memory in lambda.

The basic process steps are:

1. Outside source drops zip file in S3 bucket
2. Lambda receives S3 file created event
3. Lambda reads file, gets contents (will be plain text), and does stuff with it

The issue is decompressing the file, I've worked an example with a simple text file and that does just fine, it's getting the text file out of a zip archive that's the issue.

This is a cut down version of the lambda code, I've tried to only remove business specific logic:

```js
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const unzipper = require('unzipper');

const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_S3_REGION
});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  // Get file info from the event
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
  };

  const command = new GetObjectCommand(params);
  let bodyStream;
  try {
    const s3File = await s3.send(command);
    bodyStream = s3File.Body;
  } catch (err) {
    const message = "Error getting file";
    throw new Error(message);
  }

  let updates = [];
  bodyStream
    .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
    .on('entry', async (entry) => {
      console.log('in await loop');
      const content = await entry.buffer();
      const body = content.toString();

      // process file body here, which creates a Promise
      updates.push(promise);
    });

  // Promises generated as part of the entry event pipe
  await Promise.all(updates)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  console.log(`All updates from file ${bucket}:${key} processed`);
};
```

All the dependencies are installed properly, the lambda runs, but for whatever reason the `console.log('in await loop')` is never reached.

I know the `unzipper` library works, because this code works in my local environment and I get the expected file content to stdout:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const unzipper = require("unzipper");

fs.createReadStream("samples/file.zip")
  .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
  .on("entry", async (entry) => {
    const content = await entry.buffer();
    console.log(content.toString());
  });
```

Libraries used here are not a hard requirement, and I can `npm install` basically anything to get the job done.  If there's a better tool for this in one of the other AWS Lambda runtimes, I can use that instead, I've just defaulted to NodeJS because it's well known and supported.

Comment: In the `updates.push(promise);` line, what is "promise" referencing?  It's never defined.

Comment: @AnonCoward processing the files once unzipped makes promises that are resolved later, I thought it was important to keep that detail in, but the exact nature of the promise isn't important.  If that matters, they will be a bunch of axios requests to another service.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar problem statement recently, where I had to unzip PDF's & upload them back to the same bucket. But I did it using `decompress` package

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const https = require('https');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const decompress = require('decompress');

const s3Client = new AWS.S3({ accessKeyId: 'xxx' ,secretAccessKey: 'yyy' });

const unzipFile = async (file, unzipDirectoryPath) => {
  // NOTE: I had to get only PDF files. Hence, the filter.
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    decompress(file, unzipDirectoryPath, {
      filter: file => file.path.indexOf('__MACOSX') < 0 && path.extname(file.path) === '.pdf',
    })
      .then((files) => {
        return resolve(files);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
};

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    // get bucket & key from event
    
    const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: key };
    const response = await s3Client.getObject(params).promise();
    const zipFile = response.Body;
    
    const localUnzipDirectoryPath = `/tmp/${customPath}/`;
    const unzippedFiles = await unzipFile(zipFile, localUnzipDirectoryPath);

    // rest of your code goes here
    
    fs.rmSync(localUnzipDirectoryPath, { recursive: true, force: true });
    return;
}
```